# Castle Windsor - One class implementing multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I register my two interfaces on application start as so:-

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IEntityIndexController)).ImplementedBy(typeof(SnippetController)).LifeStyle.Transient);
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(ISnippetController)).ImplementedBy(typeof(SnippetController)).LifeStyle.Transient);
```

Then when I try to run an IoC.Resolve on an object that uses the second interface here (ISnippetController) it throws the following exception:-

*Can't create component 'MyApp.Admin.Presenters.SnippetPresenter' as it has dependencies to be satisfied. 
MyApp.Admin.Presenters.SnippetPresenter is waiting for the following dependencies: 
Services: 
- MyApp.Admin.Controllers.ISnippetController which was not registered.*

If I switch the order of the registrations around it complains that it cannot find the IEntityIndexController.  So it appears it only picks up the first registration of a class, then any further interfaces that map to that same concrete class are ignored.

Is there something obvious here that I'm missing?  (p.s. im using .net 3.5, windsor RC3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried registering with different syntax (`AddComponent<>`)?

Try updating to latest trunk version and see if it helps. Looks like a bug to me.
If it does not happen, create a test that exhibits the bug, and submit it [here](http://support.castleproject.org/projects/IOC)

Answer (score 2):

Updated to the latest trunk (1015) and used forwarded types which fixed the issue. :-)